# Pytorch model changing computational graph for each sample in a batch, how should this be done?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I need input data dependent switching of two layers and rotating output tensor in my model, so there will be different layers active and different rotations for each sample in a batch, there is no other way than basically iterate over a batch and doing forward pass with batch size 1 in this loop right? But how should this be done? For loop over a tensor batch dimension or something else?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by rotating output? Also, is it right to say that you are interested to have each item in the batch processed differently?

Comment: By rotationg I mean torch.rot90 not much important regarding my problem I think and yes I'm interested to have each item in the batch processed differently.

Comment: In that case, would it work if you just concatenate all elements in a batch into a single tensor? And configure the network to act on that. Alternatively, maybe have the information that decides how each element is processed be part of the network inputs, so that you can set dynamic batch sizes.